# Método de mi objeto no funciona

Tags: javascript

**He creado este código y lo explico además en él mismo, pero me lanza error, por qué?**

```js
Object.defineProperty(Window.prototype,'_',{get: () => new ES()});
/* Aquí hago una abreviación en la creación del objeto, de manera que al escribir 

_.get("#id");            

Sería lo mismo que:

var e = new ES().get("#id");

*/

function ES(){ // Constructor
 this.e = (tofind) => { // Esta funcion tan solo devuelve un elemento, como en jQuery con $('.class'), etc.
 var d = document;
 return tofind[0] === "#" ? d.getElementById(tofind.substr(1)) : tofind[0] === "." ? Array.from(d.getElementsByClassName(tofind.substr(1)))
     : Array.from(d.getELementsByTagName(tofind));
 };
}


for(var method in _){ 
/* Aquí busco abreviar más aún, de manera que envés de escribir:
_.get("#id") , lo haga de la forma:


get("#id"), entonces itero sobre _ , que es equivalente a new ES(), por lo tanto un OBJETO. Al iterar, cada vez que encuentra un método lo define en el prototipo de window, con:

get: _[method] , donde _ es el objeto y method es un método del objeto

*/
Object.defineProperty(Window.prototype, method, {
get: _[method]
});
console.log(`Método: 

${_[method]}`)  
}

e("#h").style.color = "green"; // Error <---------
// _.e("#h").style.color = "red"; // SIN ERROR SIN ERROR SIN ERROR
```

Comment: puedes agregar que error te da, si por consola o por lógica o que es lo esta resultando... así poder darte una respuesta mas acertada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te diría que el error está aquí:

```
Object.defineProperty(Window.prototype, method, {
  get: _[method]
});
```

Quieres que `get` sea una función/método, pero tal y como se está definiendo, parece una propiedad que no le está pasando ningún valor al método que se quiere *puentear*.

Si lo conviertes en una función con `() =>` ya funciona (he quitado los comentarios para que ocupe menos):

```js
function ES() { 
  this.e = (tofind) => {
    var d = document;
    return tofind[0] === "#" ? d.getElementById(tofind.substr(1)) : tofind[0] === "." ? Array.from(d.getElementsByClassName(tofind.substr(1))) :
      Array.from(d.getELementsByTagName(tofind));
  };
}

Object.defineProperty(Window.prototype, '_', {
  get: () => new ES()
});


for (var method in _) {
  Object.defineProperty(Window.prototype, method, {
    get: () => _[method]
  });
  console.log(`Método: ${_[method]}`)
}

e("#h").style.color = "green"; // Ya funciona
```

```html
<div id="h">Soy una H</div>
```